# Powershell and .xlsx how to use =PROPER()

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a .xlsx file that I need to correct multiple columns to use proper formatting. I've been unsuccessful trying to use =Proper(), =Lower() and even =Upper() via Powershell.

Anyone happen to know away to do this? Thanks

```
$worksheet = C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\Book1.xlsx
Import-Module PSExcel 

$worksheet.Columns("Name, 'Primary Worksite', 'Primary Job Title'").ToProper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using COM - the key is calling the [Proper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.proper) function via the [WorksheetFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) class that gives programmatic access to all of the functions built into Excel.

Other libraries and modules might provide wrappers around this for you...

```
# setup - create a new workbook with "aaa bbb ccc" in cell A1
$excel = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application;
$excel.Visible = $true;
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add();
$workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "aaa bbb ccc";

# get the text from a range
$range = $workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1");
$originalText = $range.Text;

# convert it to "Proper Case"
# (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.proper)
$properText   = $excel.WorksheetFunction.Proper($originalText);

# set the new text back into the cell
$range.Value  = $properText; # Aaa Bbb Ccc

# clean up
$workbook.Close($false);
$excel.Quit();
```